# HTML/PDF to DOC(X) in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, html, documents

I need to convert PDF or HTML+CSS into DOC or DOCX under Linux, it can be from the command line or with a scripting language.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I've just stumbled on this question and after a bit more googling, found pandoc: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html

A simple command will create a docx or pdf (or rtf etc) file from html input like so:

```
pandoc -o output.docx input.html
```

It can also write to stdout (with some formats) and read from stdin.

Not sure if it's in the debian / ubuntu repos but it's in the epel 6 repo for Redhat / CentOS 6 ( `yum install pandoc` ).

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do the latter using OpenOffice from the command line. There are also bridges for Scripting languages - find out more on OpenOffice's website. There is one for PHP called [PUNO](http://puno.sourceforge.net/site.html), however I have no personal experience with it yet.

Comment: It parses HTML very badly, ignoring most of it's CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HTML into .doc using an OpenOffice macro, see this thread:

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=44367#44367

converting pdf to .doc is much harder, due the multitude of different content that could be inside a PDF - quite often PDFs are used for things such as scanned text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pdftohtml`](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) to make an html file from a pdf.

Word can open html files directly.

Answer (score -1):

> ## [Document Conversion](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=84057)
>
> [Current list of past examples.](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12922)
>
> [Convert any document type into PDF](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=62219#62219)
>
> [How convert Powerpoint slides to jpeg
>   using openoffice api? (slide splitter)](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8715)
>
> [List of many past conversion examples](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4998)
>
> [Filter list](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3549)
>
> [List of converters available in OOo
>   2.0 (1.9.x)? Instructions to produce filter list](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=21404)
>
> [Recursive Folder of Html into
>   PDF,Txt,SXW,DOC](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45659#45659)
>
> [Recursive Folder of SXD to SDC
>   (StarCalc 5)](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=17247)
>
> [Setting Image size for JPEG export](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11838)
>
> [Xcel to Calc conversion using the API](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2668)
>
> [A very similar one, converting Xcel to
>   Text](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2819)
>
> [Batch mode conversion](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=16056#16056)
>
> [Document conversion](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4163)
>
> [VB: converting Excel files to txt
>   files](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3194)
>
> [General Visual Basic document
>   conversion of Text...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=22034#22034)
>
> Converting Word -> PDF from the
>   command line
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3772
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5513
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3768
>
> [PyOpenOffice tool to convert SXW to
>   PDF without using OOo](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12757)
>
> [Convert Word --> Writer from the
>   command line](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=24891#24891)
>
> Convert Excel -> PDF from the command
>   line
>
> http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5596
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=21050#21050
>
> [Convert SXC to CSV from commandline](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6987)
>
> [Convert PPT to HTML from command
>   line...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5137)
>
> [Convert PPT to HTML short example...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9437)
>
> [Convert PPT to PDF short example...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=76969#76969)
>
> [see tail end of thread...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3772)
>
> [Converting SXW -> PDF](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3017)
>
> [Draw export to PDF](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3545)
>
> [In Python...](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3451)
>
> [Thread about converting document to
>   PDF in Java](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1480)
>
> Convert SXW to DOC with Java
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=81846#81846
>
> I wrote a batch document converter
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3525
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2810
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=10311#10311
>   you can get it here
>   http://www.ooomacros.org/user.php#95532
>   more discussion of it here...
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5708
>
> Macro to save in three formats
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3612
>   Macro to save backups with timestamps
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7674
>
> Open HTML with Writer not Web in order
>   to export
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3973
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=44367#44367
>   How to convert HTML into OpenOffice
>   File?
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11580
>   Page size pblm when converting HTML to
>   PDF
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=63682#63682
>
> Discussion that ends in DocConverter
>   utility.
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2668
>
> Convert DBF into XLS, SXC, PDF and
>   HTML
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5728
>
> Good Visual Basic code
>   example...converting documents
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7673
>
> Draw exporting and printing
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3620
>
> Using OOo's source code to read /
>   convert / write documents in the
>   formats supported by its filters. 
>   http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5785

Comment: no one works for me